# Using the Symfony admin generator to let a user manage a subset of record

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

My first post here, hopefully It will be right! =)

I am creating a site to manage web application development using symfony 1.4 and doctrine.
My records consist for this problem of Project and ProjectFeatures

Now what I want to do is use the admin generator to let users manage the features for one project thru a link constraining all the returned features by project_id, that would look like: http://mysite/member/project/:project_id/features

in my routing.yml configuration, I have:

> ```
> member_project_feature:  
>   class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection  
>     options:
>       model:                ProjectFeature
>       module:               memberProjectFeature
>       prefix_path:          /member/project/:project_id/features
>       with_show:            true
>       column:               id
>       with_wildcard_routes: true
> ```

project_id is an existing column in the model ProjectFeature,
I will use a custom query to retrieve features only by that project_id.

Now I can generate a url to link to that admin generator module without error using:
`url_for('member_project_feature', array('project_id' => $project['id']))`

And the routing system does recognise the url:
`May 04 14:30:59 symfony [info] {sfPatternRouting} Match route "member_project_feature" (/member/project/:project_id/features.:sf_format) for /member/project/1/features with parameters array (  'module' => 'memberProjectFeature',  'action' => 'index',  'sf_format' => 'html',  'project_id' => '1',)`

But the admin generator can't generate it's links inside it's templates with that prefix_path and returns error **InvalidArgumentException** with message **The "/member/project/:project_id/features/:action/action.:sf_format" route has some missing mandatory parameters (:project_id).**

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found my answer at this url: http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/?s=symfony
But I will give it here and shorten it because, stackoverflow is awesome and it should be there for a long time =)

1st - The routing configuration I used in my question is valid.
2nd - You need to add a method in the action file generated by the admin

```
public function execute($sfRequest)
{
  // taken from http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/?s=symfony
  $this->forward404Unless(
    $project_id = $sfRequest->getUrlParameter('project_id'));

   $this->forward404Unless(
     $this->project = Doctrine::getTable('ttcWebProject')->find($project_id));

   $this->getContext()->getRouting()
     ->setDefaultParameter('project_id', $project_id);

   if ($id = $sfRequest->getUrlParameter('id'))
   {
     $this->getContext()->getRouting()->setDefaultParameter('id', $id);
   }

   $result = parent::execute($sfRequest);

   return $result;
 }
```

At this point the url gets generated correctly but here is the last step to get to the end result you most probably want to achieve:

3rd - To get the list by project_id I can either provide a table method in the generator.yml, a default value to the getFilterDefaults or this method in the action file:

```
protected function buildQuery ()
{
  $q = parent::buildQuery();
  $rootAlias = $q->getRootAlias();
  $q->andWhere("{$rootAlias}.project_id = ?", 
    $this->getRequest()->getUrlParameter('project_id'));

   return $q;
 }
```

Comment: just a quick comment. the author of the blog posts has updated his posts so the create action works in the subcontroller...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain about what you're trying to do here, but it sounds like you need the `ProjectFeature::toParams` method return the project_id.

Comment: Hi, I want to use the :projet_id in the route to make sure that every action within this admin generated module is related to a project specified by :project_id in the url. The list of feature will be for this project_id, new feature will be for this project_id. Basically I want to this the admin generator to generate all urls with the :project_id parameter

Comment: And I tried with a toParams method and it could work for links generated for one object but not for collection links such as filters or index. And it did not work anyways. Maybe it works with propel? maybe it's deprecated? (http://tohenk.wordpress.com/2009/04/22/using-multiple-primary-keys-in-admin-generator/)